# Android sensor manager-react native error

Tags: android, react-native

I need to access accelerometer in my react native app. Apparently the only one for Android is [this one](https://github.com/kprimice/react-native-sensor-manager/) and it does not work. Ive even tried it on a separate clean project and still shows `undefined is not an object (evaluating mSensorManager.startAccelerometer)`. I'm using the sample code provided in readme, **What am I doing wrong?**

PS: I'm using an actual device, not a VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved [here](https://github.com/kprimice/react-native-sensor-manager/issues/12). I added to MainActivity.java following code:

```
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.sensormanager.SensorManagerPackage;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
            new MainReactPackage(), 
            new SensorManagerPackage() 
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to follow the steps in the README file.
after you do the `npm i react-native-sensor-manager --save` , 
instead of doing `rnpm link` , my approach was to do `react-native link react-native-sensor-manager` and you are done.

import it using `import { SensorManager } from 'NativeModules'`

It would definitely work.